# Comparing strings - Java

Tags: java, string, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I'm new to Java. And I've following problem:

```
string s = "someword";

if (s == "someword")
// do something
```

Sometimes doesn't work for me. Don't know why.

Thanks for responds.

Comment: Use `equals` to compare string.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but for someone new to Java, it's not a bad question.  I can see voting to close, but downvoting?  We were all new once, too.

Comment: @DavidStratton It's not being downvoted because it's stupid, it's being downvoted because it's been asked dozens if not hundreds of times

Comment: OK, sorry for that and thanks for responds :)

Comment: In java, you need to compare string like this, if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("someword"), if you want case sensitve then, if(s.equals("someword")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java `==` compare reference. Use `.equals()` for compare value.

Duplication of this: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)